# TPC Inheritance 1 base class with 2 children inheriting, 1 class property computed, other class property not computed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a project that has two classes and one base class.  The base class holds all the common properties between the Projects and Programs Model.  Projects are associated to Programs via the ProgramID column. Projects has an editable field for ProgramID to let the users pick what program they want to associate the project to (Not not all projects have a program, thats why its nullable).

Essentially, I want to have Projects be able to read and write to the database and Programs to just read (No set).  Is this possible with TPC inheritance?  Any suggestions are welcomed.  If more information is needed, I am happy to provide it.  Thank you in advance for your help!

**Base Class**

```
public abstract class PMBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual int? ProgramID { get; set; }

    public virtual Program Program { get; set; }

    //Omitted rest of Model
}
```

**Program Class**

```
public class Program : PMBase
{
    [Column("PMGroupID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public override int? ProgramID { get { return ProjectID; } set { value = null; } }

    //NOTE: Database column names were from legacy changes.  I wish we could change this, but we do not have time.
    [Column("ProgramID")]
    public override int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PMBase> Projects { get; set; }

    //Omitted rest of Model
}
```

**Project Class**

```
public class Project : PMBase
{
    [Display(Name = "Program Number & Name")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public override int? ProgramID { get; set; }

    //Omitted rest of Model
}
```

**dbContext mapping**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
  .Map(prj =>
  {
    prj.MapInheritedProperties();
    prj.ToTable("Projects");
  });

modelBuilder.Entity<Program>()
  .Map(pgm =>
  {
    pgm.MapInheritedProperties();
    pgm.ToTable("Programs");
  });

modelBuilder.Entity<PMBase>()
  .HasOptional(prj => prj.Program)
  .WithMany(pgm => pgm.Projects)
  .HasForeignKey(prj => prj.ProgramID);
```

**Errors messages seen**

These errors where seen when trying various things.  I feel I am close when I see `UNION` error, but cant seem to get past that.

> The column \"PMGroupID\" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.
>
> The override foreign key component 'ProgramID' is not a declared property on type 'Project'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.
>
> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Comment: Why do you need to use the same property names to mean different things in the different concrete classes? You could have uniquely named properties associated with the primary and foreign key columns in Program and Project, and if you do need to refer to PMBase.ProgramID make it an abstract property in PMBase, derived from the correct column in each concrete class, and ignored by Entity Framework.

Comment: @Rattle - I currently have it setup that way because we have a search function via Expression trees that has to have properties inherit from the PMBase.  I think there is a way I can work around that though.  Could you provide an example of the concrete properties refering to the abstract property?  It could be that its Monday and early, but I am not following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking Rattles' suggestion, I was able to get the model working as I would expect.

By creating a abstract getter I was able to successfully use it as a property on my search functions.  With the getter just reading the concrete properties, it made the models easier to use/maintain.  I was then able to then use the ProgramID property in Project only.  Thank you for the suggestion Rattle!

**Base Class**

```
public abstract class PMBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual int? PMGroupID { get { return ProgramIDGetter(); } }
    public abstract int? ProgramIDGetter();


//Omitted rest of Model
}
```

**Program Class**

```
public class Program : PMBase
{
    public override int? ProgramIDGetter()
    {
        return this.ProjectID;
    }

    //NOTE: Database column names were from legacy changes.  I wish we could change this, but we do not have time.
    [Column("ProgramID")]
    public override int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    //Omitted rest of Model

}
```

**Project Class**

```
public class Project : PMBase
{

    public override int? ProgramIDGetter()
    {
        return this.ProgramID;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Program Number & Name")]
    public override int? ProgramID { get; set; }

    //Omitted rest of Model
}
```

**dbContext mapping**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
  .Map(prj =>
  {
    prj.MapInheritedProperties();
    prj.ToTable("Projects");
  });

modelBuilder.Entity<Program>()
  .Map(pgm =>
  {
    pgm.MapInheritedProperties();
    pgm.ToTable("Programs");
  });

modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
  .HasOptional(prj => prj.Program)
  .WithMany(pgm => pgm.Projects)
  .HasForeignKey(prj => prj.ProgramID);
```